# R Studio - How to get the percentile for which benchmark lies in

Tags: r, dplyr, percentile

I have below data frame. I want to find out which percentile of "value" does each "benchmark" lie. For example, "benchmark" of 100 is about 75th percentile of "value".

[image]

```
group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
benchmark <- c(100,100,100,200,200,200)
value <- c(50,80,120,150,230,250)
d_f <- data.frame(group,benchmark, value)

d_f %>%
  group_by(group, benchmark) %>%
  summarise(q25 = quantile(value, 0.25),
            q50 = quantile(value, 0.50),
            q75 = quantile(value, 0.75)
            # can add more percentile
            )
```

Another way to do is, I will list out 100 percentile points, (1th - 100th percentiles). If the "benchmark" is similar to any percentile, set the output to be that percentile.

Thank you!

Comment: 40 means benchmark=200 is about 40th percentile of value column. I'm planning to show all 100 percentile points in the output so to keep it short, I just showed 25,50,75. That won't affect "which percentile of value does each benchmark lie" column.

Comment: Is that of the entire `value` column or of the `value`s within `group`? Do you know "truth" numbers? My guess is that if grouped, `ecdf(d_f$value[1:3])(100)` is what you need here (easy to extend). If not grouped, then `ecdf(d_f$value)(c(100,200))` will give you both percentiles for the benchmarks. (Both are `[0,1]`, will need `*100`.)

Comment: Thanks for your idea! It should be per group. However, I think the result for bench_pctile for 100 should be 75th, not 66.6th. Is it calculated wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `ecdf`. The remaining question (for me) is if your empirical cumulative distribution is per group or as a whole.

Per-group:

```
d_f %>%
  group_by(group, benchmark) %>%
  mutate(bench_pctile = ecdf(value)(benchmark) * 100)
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
# # Groups:   group, benchmark [2]
#   group benchmark value bench_pctile
#   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     1       100    50         66.7
# 2     1       100    80         66.7
# 3     1       100   120         66.7
# 4     2       200   150         33.3
# 5     2       200   230         33.3
# 6     2       200   250         33.3
```

Or from the entire column, where we need the `ecdf` call before grouping:

```r
valecdf <- ecdf(d_f$value)
d_f %>%
  group_by(group, benchmark) %>%
  mutate(bench_pctile = valecdf(benchmark) * 100)
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
# # Groups:   group, benchmark [2]
#   group benchmark value bench_pctile
#   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     1       100    50         33.3
# 2     1       100    80         33.3
# 3     1       100   120         33.3
# 4     2       200   150         66.7
# 5     2       200   230         66.7
# 6     2       200   250         66.7
```

One way to back this up is with an approximation:

```r
### grouped
mean(100 <= d_f$value[1:3])
# [1] 0.3333333
mean(200 <= d_f$value[4:6])
# [1] 0.6666667

### ungrouped
mean(100 <= d_f$value)
# [1] 0.6666667
mean(200 <= d_f$value)
# [1] 0.3333333
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea! It should be per group. However, I think the result for bench_pctile for 100 should be 75th, not 66.6th. Is it calculated wrong?

Comment: The `mean(x <= a)` approximation works well when the value to be checked is present (or near one) in the dataset. So not, it's not a great approximation. `quantile(d_f$value[1:3], seq(0,1,len=11))` certainly suggests 75%. I don't know what `ecdf` is doing differently here ...